# How do I specify more than one validator in a genesis.json file

Tags: ethereum

I am trying to create a private ETH network. I have this genesis.json file.

```json
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 7484,
    ...
    "clique": {
      "period": 2,
      "epoch": 30000
    }
  },
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
  "timestamp": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000<validator1>0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x47b760",
  "difficulty": "0x1",
  "mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "alloc": {
    "<validator1>": {
      "balance": "0x33B2E3C9FD0803CE8000000"
    },
  },
  "number": "0x0",
  "gasUsed": "0x0",
  "baseFeePerGas": "0x3B9ACA00"
}
```

How do I specify more than one validators in the genesis file.